# Lista contando elementos

Tags: python, lista

Tenho um lista, assim:

```
L = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Se usasse o comando `SET`:

```
L = [0,1]
sum(L) = 2
```

A resposta que preciso seria: 3. Cada par de resposta seria um ponto, como tem dois '0' = 1, um ponto, três '1' = 2

OBS: Desculpe mas formulei de forma incompleta a pergunta por isso revisei

Comment: Se fizer apenas `sum(L)` como lista terá o resultado 3. Qual o intuito de utilizar o `set`? E de que forma você conseguiu o resultado 2 com `sum`? Aliás, você precisa contar o número de elementos ou somá-los? Texto diz uma coisa, código diz outra.

Comment: "A resposta que preciso seria: 3" E esse `3` é o que mais em concreto ?

Comment: Eu estou tentando entender a sua dúvida, melhore o texto e quem sabe eu posso te ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para somar o conteúdo de uma sequência, basta usar o `sum`. Se quer somar todos os números da lista, não deve, claro, reduzi-la antes a um conjunto usando `set`.

Já, para contar o número de ocorrências de cada elemento em uma sequência (como uma lista) ou um iterável (como as linhas um arquivo aberto), você pode usar o collections.Counter - que automaticamente agrupa as ocorrências num objeto que pode ser lido como se fosse um dicionário:

```
In [3]: from collections import Counter

In [4]: L = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]

In [5]: Counter(L)
Out[5]: Counter({0: 2, 1: 3})

In [6]: Counter(L)[1]
Out[6]: 3
```

Confira a documentação do Counter em:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: Obrigado, vc respondeu o que eu precisava

Answer (score 0):

o set() não permite valores repetidos. Se você quer somar 3 vezes o mesmo valor (1) você deve usar a list(), e não set().

```
>>> lista = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
>>> print(sum(lista)) 
3
```